# LARAVEL 5.4 ROLE ON MIDDLEWARE

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

i'm trying to setup my role on routing using middleware, but everytime i log in into my system, it redirects back on my login view.

here is my routing

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']],function(){
Route::get('dashboard','RouteController@adminDashboard');
  Route::get('admin',function(){
    return 'this is admin page';
  });
});
```

and here is my middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::User()->id_role == 1){
      return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect::to('dashboard');
}
```

can u guys helpme.

Comment: I'm not sure but you should check this out, you're redirected to `home` once logged in by default. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Answer (score 0):

If login is successful then the middleware checks the id, if the id is 1 then you return the next request (`$next($request);`). Your redirect never occurs. 
So the next request is handled by your `adminDashboard` function in `RouteController`.

You should return your view in `RouteController` like this:

```
public function adminDashboard() {
    return view('your-path-to-your-dashboard');
}
```

and change your route to this

```
Route::get('/', 'RouteController@adminDashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the initial slash.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']],function(){
  Route::get('/dashboard','RouteController@adminDashboard');
  Route::get('/admin',function(){
return 'this is admin page';
```

});
})

Or inside your controllers declare a construct function like this:

```
public function __contstruct(){
   $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Followed by your usual functions